# QGIS reshape features to close indents in polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, close

Have already run the buffer tool and do not want to make the polygons any larger with another buffer run.

Reshape features tool seems like it should work I am just not seeing how to operate it after many attempts and online searches.

Screenshot is [image: here] , showing how these large indents need to be eliminated, closed, or whatever the term is called?

Arcgis has an editor tool that does this but I need to use QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out it. 
Single left clicks when reshaping followed by a left click to end reshape, then single right click to complete reshape. 
Ignore the errors about duplicate nodes. 
Save edits often.
A little clunky interface but gets the job done.
BTW, this is for a tree canopy survey using Orfeo output and raster2vector.